# Why does syslog.h not have a standard GNU header

Tags: linux, gcc, gnu

Since syslog is part of the GNU C runtime library, why does it not have the standard GNU license header and exemption. Instead it has a 'Regents of the University of California' licensing header. I thought I understood the licensing for development under Linux but this makes me doubt myself.

Comment: Heard of it - yes, but that's all. This is my first Linux project so what I don't know far exceeds what I do know. So why have I got BSD and GNU headers ?

Comment: "I thought I understood the licensing for development under Linux" - best not to lump all Free Software together and call it "Linux". Technically, Linux is a kernel, and glibc is a C library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LICENSES` file shipped with a current glibc mentions that it includes some code from BSD4.4. Quoting from the `INSTALL` file that used to ship with glibc cca. 2009:

> Most of the math functions are taken from 4.4 BSD; they have been
>   modified only slightly to work with the GNU C library.  The
>   Internet-related code (most of the `inet' subdirectory) and several
>   other miscellaneous functions and header files have been included with
>   little or no modification.

This is why the headers remain preserved.

Anyway, the [BSD licenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses) are very permissive, and they do allow doing what glibc did with them.

Comment: Thanks for a very clear answer. As you say the license is permissive but includes a requirement for copyright attribution even with a binary only distribution. So when doing Linux development do you need to check every header file ?

Comment: Apologies. I don't know what you mean by "Linux development".

Comment: Sorry. I only started using gcc when I started developing for Linux so I tend to talk as if they were the same thing. I meant when using the GNU C library.

Comment: It should be quite okay to write proprietary C programs which when run on a machine where the C library is glibc will be dynamically linked against it. This is because glibc is [LGPL'd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License). I don't know the details. But the wiki page does explain them.